# Why castle.windsor injecting dll more than once

Tags: c#, dll, castle-windsor, ioc-container, dll-injection

I'm using castle.windsor version 3.3 for .net 3.5.
I have a weird issue,
It seems my app loads dll more than once.

i'm loading the assembly with:

```
WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.Named([AssemblyName]);
```

When I check the container's nodes (after the registration), every assembly have only one occurrence,
but when i check what dll my application is loading (via process explorer), 
I can see same dll more than once, with the same version and path.

Also, i want to add that my application works just fine,

but loading dll multiple time is not a normal behavior.

thanks.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: i'm asking if someone also had this problem

Comment: What is the problem?